# ¿El comando getRevieweeIds requiere permisos de maquina?

Tags: php

Se me esta presentando un error en php cuando trato de usar el comando:

```
($user_obj->getRevieweeIds())
```

me sale algo como:

> **¡Acceso prohibido!** Usted no tiene permiso para acceder al objeto solicitado. El objeto está protegido contra lectura o el servidor no
>   puede leerlo.
>
> Si usted cree que esto es un error del servidor, por favor
>   comuníqueselo al administrador del portal.
>
> **Error 403** localhost Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o PHP/5.6.37

El error inicial sale así:

```
List de Documentos', @$_REQUEST['last_message']); if($GLOBALS['CONFIG']['treeview'] != "On"){ sort_browser(); } $secureurl_obj = new phpsecureurl; $user_obj = new User($_SESSION['uid'], $GLOBALS['connection'], $GLOBALS['database']); if($user_obj->isReviewer() && sizeof($user_obj->getRevieweeIds()) > 0) { echo '
 **tiene '. sizeof($user_obj->getRevieweeIds()). ' documentos '; if (sizeof($user_obj->getRevieweeIds()) != 1) { echo 's'; } echo ' Para Revisar, haga click para ver detalle !**

'; } $rejected_files_obj = $user_obj->getRejectedFileIds(); if(isset($rejected_files_obj[0]) && $rejected_files_obj[0] != null) { echo ' '. sizeof($rejected_files_obj) . ' de sus documentos fueron rechazados! 
'; } $llen = $user_obj->getNumExpiredFiles(); if($llen > 0) { echo ' '. $llen . ' de su documento (s), expiraron! 
'; } // get a list of documents the user has "view" permission for // get current user's information-->department if(!isset($_GET['starting_index'])) { $_GET['starting_index'] = 0; } if(!isset($_GET['stoping_index'])) { $limit=$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['page_limit']; $_GET['stoping_index'] = ($_GET['starting_index']+$limit-1); } if(!isset($_GET['sort_by'])) { $_GET['sort_by'] = 'id'; } if(!isset($_GET['sort_order'])) { $_GET['sort_order'] = 'asc'; } if(!isset($_GET['page'])) { $_GET['page'] = 0; } //set values $page_url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?submit=true'; $user_perms = new UserPermission($_SESSION['uid'], $GLOBALS['connection'], $GLOBALS['database']); //$start_P = getmicrotime(); $file_id_array = $user_perms->getViewableFileIds(); //$end_P = getmicrotime(); $count = sizeof($file_id_array); //$lsort_b = getmicrotime(); $sorted_id_array = my_sort($file_id_array, $_GET['sort_order'], $_GET['sort_by']); //$lsort_e = getmicrotime(); //$sorted_obj_array = $user_perms->convertToFileDataOBJ($sorted_id_array); //$llist_b = getmicrotime(); // Patch by jonathanwminer if($GLOBALS['CONFIG']['treeview'] == "On") { $_GET['starting_index'] = 0; $_GET['stoping_index'] = sizeof($sorted_id_array); } if($GLOBALS['CONFIG']['treeview'] != 'On') { echo ''; echo '
'; list_files($sorted_id_array, $user_perms, $page_url, $GLOBALS['CONFIG']['dataDir'], $_GET['sort_order'], $_GET['sort_by'], $_GET['starting_index'], $_GET['stoping_index'], 'false','false'); $limit=$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['page_limit']; $total_hit = sizeof($file_id_array); list_nav_generator($total_hit, $limit, $GLOBALS['CONFIG']['num_page_limit'], $page_url, $_GET['page'], $_GET['sort_by'], $_GET['sort_order']);   //$llist_e = getmicrotime(); // clean up echo '
'; } if($GLOBALS['CONFIG']['treeview'] == 'On') { if(is_array($sorted_id_array) && $sorted_id_array[0] != '') { show_tree($sorted_id_array, $_GET['starting_index'], $_GET['stoping_index']); } } //draw_footer();  //echo '
Load Page Time: ' . (getmicrotime() - $start_time) . ' '; //echo '
Load Permission Time: ' . ($end_P - $start_P) . ' ';    //echo '
Load Sort Time: ' . ($lsort_e - $lsort_b) . ' ';    //echo '
Load Table Time: ' . ($llist_e - $llist_b) . ' ';   ?>
```

He entrado a varios foros pero no me ha funcionado los consejos que me han brindado, no se si es que falta algo al directorio o si es un tema de permisos 
La version del php es 5.6.

De antemano agradezco si me pueden guiar.

**Buenas noches esta es la user_class**
**Buenas noches esta es la user_class**

```
<?php
/*
User_class.php - Container for user related info
Copyright (C) 2002, 2003, 2004  Stephen Lawrence, Khoa Nguyen

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.
*/

if( !defined('User_class') )
{
  define('User_class', 'true', false);

  class User extends databaseData
  {
    var $root_username;
        /**
         * 
         * 
         **/
        function User($id, $connection, $database)
        {
                $this->root_username = $GLOBALS['CONFIG']['root_username'];
                $this->field_name = 'username';
                $this->field_id = 'id';
                $this->tablename = $GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix'] . $this->TABLE_USER;
                $this->result_limit = 1; //there is only 1 user with a certain user_name or user_id
            databaseData::setTableName($this->TABLE_USER);
            databaseData::databaseData($id, $connection, $database);
    }

    /**
     * Return department name for current user
     * @return string
     */
    function getDeptName()
    {
            $query = "SELECT {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}department.name FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}department, {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}user WHERE {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}user.id = $this->id and {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}user.department={$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}department.id";
            $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in query" .mysql_error() );
            if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
            {
                    list($department) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
                    return $department;
            }
            else
            {
                    $this->error = 'ID no Unico : ' . $this->uid;
            }
            return -1;
    }

    /**
    * Return department ID for current user
    * @return string
    */
    function getDeptId() {
        $query = "SELECT {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}user.department FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}user WHERE {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}user.id = $this->id";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in query".mysql_error());

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            list($department) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            return $department;
        }
        $this->error = 'ID no Unico: '.$this->id;
        return - 1;

    }

    /**
     * Return an array of publishable documents
     * @return array
     * @param object $publishable
     */
    function getPublishedData($publishable)
    {
            $data_published = array();
            $index = 0;
            $query = "SELECT {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}data.id FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}data, {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}user WHERE {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}data.owner = $this->id and {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}user.id = {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}data.owner and {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}data.publishable = $publishable";
            $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in query: ". $query .mysql_error());
            while($index<mysql_num_rows($result))
            {
                    list($data_published[$index]) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
                    $index++;
            }
            return $data_published;
    }

    /**
     * Check whether user from object has Admin rights
     * @return Boolean
     */ 
    function isAdmin()
    {
            if ($this->isRoot())
            {
                return true;
            }
            $query = "SELECT {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}admin.admin FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}admin WHERE {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}admin.id = $this->id";
            $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in querying: $query" . mysql_error() );
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) !=1 )
            {
                return false;
            }

            list($isadmin) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            return $isadmin;
    }

    /**
     * Check whether user from object is root
     * @return 
     */
function isRoot()
{
    return ($this->root_username == $this->getName());
}

function getPassword()
{
    $query = "SELECT $this->tablename.password FROM $this->tablename WHERE $this->tablename.id=$this->id";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in querying: $query" . mysql_error() );
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) !=1 )
    {
        header('Location:error.php?ec=14');
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        list($passwd) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        return $passwd;
    }
}

function changePassword($non_encrypted_password)
{
    $query = "UPDATE $this->tablename SET $this->tablename.password=password('". addslashes($non_encrypted_password) ."') WHERE $this->tablename.id=$this->id";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in querying: $query" . mysql_error() );
    return true;
}

function validatePassword($non_encrypted_password)
{
    $query = "SELECT $this->tablename.username FROM $this->tablename WHERE $this->tablename.id=$this->id and password= password('". addslashes($non_encrypted_password) ."')";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in querying: $query" . mysql_error() );
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
            {
            return true;
            }
    return false;
}

function changeName($new_name)
{
    $query = "UPDATE $this->tablename SET $this->tablename.username='$new_name' WHERE $this->tablename.id=$this->id";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in querying: $query" . mysql_error() );
    return true;
}

function isReviewer()
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}dept_reviewer where user_id = " . $this->id;
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die('Error in query: '. $query . mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
function getAllRevieweeIds() // this functions assume that you are a root thus allowing you to by pass everything
{
    $lquery = "SELECT id FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}$this->TABLE_DATA WHERE {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}$this->TABLE_DATA.publishable = 0";
    $lresult = mysql_query($lquery, $this->connection) or die("Error in query: $query" . mysql_error());
    $lfile_data = array();
    $lnum_files = mysql_num_rows($lresult);
    for($lindex = 0; $lindex< $lnum_files; $lindex++)
    {
        list($lfid) = mysql_fetch_row($lresult);
        $lfile_data[$lindex] = $lfid;
    }
    return $lfile_data;
}
function getRevieweeIds() //return an array of files that need reviewing under this person
{
    if($this->isReviewer())
    {
        $query = "SELECT dept_id FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}$this->TABLE_DEPT_REVIEWER WHERE user_id = ".$this->id;
        $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in query: $query" . mysql_error());
        $num_depts = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $query = "SELECT id FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}data WHERE (";
        for($index = 0; $index < $num_depts; $index++)
        {
            list($dept) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            if($index != $num_depts -1)
                $query = $query . " {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}data.department = $dept or";
            else 
                $query = $query . " {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}data.department = $dept )";
        }
        $query = $query . " and {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}data.publishable = 0";
        mysql_free_result($result);
        $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in query: $query" . mysql_error());
        $file_data = array();
        $num_files = mysql_num_rows($result);
        for($index = 0; $index< $num_files; $index++)
        {
            list($fid) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $file_data[$index] = $fid;
        }
        return $file_data;              
    }       
}
function getAllRejectedFileIds()
{
    $query = "SELECT id FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}$this->TABLE_DATA WHERE publishable = '-1'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in query: $query" . mysql_error());
    $file_data = array();
    $num_files = mysql_num_rows($result);
    for($index = 0; $index< $num_files; $index++)
    {
        list($fid) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $file_data[$index] = $fid;
    }
    return $file_data;
}
function getRejectedFileIds()
{
    $query = "SELECT id FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}data WHERE publishable = '-1' and owner = ".$this->id;
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in query: $query" . mysql_error());
    $file_data = array();
    $num_files = mysql_num_rows($result);
    for($index = 0; $index< $num_files; $index++)
    {
        list($fid) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $file_data[$index] = $fid;
    }
    return $file_data;
}
function getExpiredFileIds()
{
    $lquery = "SELECT id FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}data WHERE status=-1 AND owner = '$this->id'";
    $lresult = mysql_query($lquery) or die(mysql_error());
    $llen = mysql_num_rows($lresult);
    $file_data = array();
    for($index = 0; $index< $llen; $index++)
    {
        list($fid) = mysql_fetch_row($lresult);
        $file_data[$index] = $fid;
    }
    return $file_data;
}
function getNumExpiredFiles()
{
    $lquery = "SELECT id FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}data WHERE status=-1 AND owner = '$this->id'";
    $lresult = mysql_query($lquery) or die(mysql_error());
    return mysql_num_rows($lresult);
}
function getEmailAddress()
{
    $query = "SELECT Email FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}user WHERE id=".$this->id;
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in query: $query" . mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 1)
    {
        echo('LLave no unica');
        exit;
    }
    list($email) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    mysql_free_result($result);
    return $email;
}

function getPhoneNumber()        
{
    $query = "SELECT phone FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}user WHERE id=".$this->id; 
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in query: $query" . mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 1)
    {
        echo('LLave no unica');
        exit; 
    }
    list($phone) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    mysql_free_result($result);
    return $phone;
}

function getFullName()//Return full name array where array[0]=firstname and array[1]=lastname        
{
    $query = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM {$GLOBALS['CONFIG']['db_prefix']}user WHERE id=".$this->id;
    $result = mysql_query($query, $this->connection) or die("Error in query: $query" . mysql_error()); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 1)
    {
        echo('LLave no unica');
        exit;
    }
    list($full_name[0], $full_name[1]) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    mysql_free_result($result);
    return $full_name;
}
```

}
}

Comment: Estás utilizando algún framework? Puedes poner el código de tu clase users?

Comment: el código es largo

Comment: Jakala  trato de pegar el codigo pero me sale que supera los caracteres permitidos cuando trato de editar, no se si doy respuesta a la pregunta

Comment: no me deja por editar ni por respuesta

Comment: buenas noches Jakala  copie la user_class

Comment: Realmente la clase se llama `User`.  lo de `User_Class` es para asegurar que exista la clase (es una variable para saberlo). Aparentemente esta correcto. Puede ser que ese archivo no tenga permisos de lectura? prueba con un `chmod 755` sobre el archivo, a ver si te deja